# postgresql: time stored as text. how to query with respect to time

Tags: postgresql

I have a table called device with following data types

```
device table:

column        Type
id            integer
created       text
name          text
```

Here the time is stored in `text` type instead of `timestamp`

Eg: `created` value `12/19/2020 20:40:23`

I try to query with this date time.

```
SELECT "device"."id",
       "device"."created",
       "device"."name",
FROM "device"
WHERE "device"."created" < '12/19/2020 20:40:23'
LIMIT 21
```

the results are not as per datetime order. it might be comparing some text string.

So what is the best solution in this case to get data w.r.t time eventhough its stored as text

Comment: This is  a **really**, really bad idea. Do you have a chance to fix that broken database design?

Comment: yes, I can. What do you suggest to do.Is it better to convert it into timestamp with zone. Also i have to index this column in future, its a lot of data, every sec two rows get added. P

Comment: Yes you should convert it to a `timestamptz` (or at least `timestamp`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the text to timestamp.  In this case a simple convertion suffices.

```
SELECT device.id,
       device.created,
       device.name,
FROM device
WHERE device.created::timestamp < '12/19/2020 20:40:23'
LIMIT 21
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because strings are compared lexicographically. Use `to_timestamp` with a format specification string to convert text to timestamp and then compare timestamps.
If you format date-time strings according to [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) then you can cast them directly to timestamp.
Unless this is a (foreign?) table out of your control do *not* store timestamps as formatted text.

```sql
SELECT id, created, name
FROM device
WHERE to_timestamp(created, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') < '2020-12-19 20:40:23'::timestamp
LIMIT 21;
```

And btw you do not need quoting.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution in this case would be to convert the `created` column from text to timestamp using the `ALTER TABLE` statement. This will allow you to use proper date and time functions and operators when querying the table, ensuring that the results are sorted in the correct order.

For example, you can use the following SQL statement to convert the `created` column to timestamp:

```
ALTER TABLE device
ALTER COLUMN created SET DATA TYPE TIMESTAMP USING 
to_timestamp(created, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
```

This statement uses the `to_timestamp` function to convert the text values in the `created` column to timestamps using the format `MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS` which match the format of your text date.

Once you have made this change, you can now query the table using proper date and time functions and operators, like so:

```
SELECT "device"."id",
       "device"."created",
       "device"."name",
FROM "device"
WHERE "device"."created" < '12/19/2020 20:40:23'::timestamp
ORDER BY created
LIMIT 21
```